# iconv translit table of characters

Tags: ascii, glibc, iconv

iconv can convert special characters like ö (odiaeresis) to ascii characters like o when used with //TRANSLIT. Is there a table of characters somewhere that lists how those transformations work? I already poked around the [source code](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/tree/master/iconv) but am not familiar enough with c to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why don't you get a list of all the Latin characters in Unicode in a file?  You can probably copy and paste it from a website.  Then run iconv //translit on that file and see what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is defined in the file `translit.def`. You may find it inside the libiconv. The library might be download at: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libiconv/.  I've extracted the first few lines of the table, which are displayed bellow:

```
# Definition of transliteration from Unicode to poorer character sets.
#
# This covers all of Markus Kuhn's TARGET1.
#
# The second column gives the transliteration. It is enclosed between tabs!
#
00A0            # NO-BREAK SPACE
00A1    !       # INVERTED EXCLAMATION MARK
00A2    c       # CENT SIGN
00A3    lb      # POUND SIGN
00A4            # CURRENCY SIGN
00A5    yen     # YEN SIGN
00A6    |       # BROKEN BAR
00A7    SS      # SECTION SIGN
00A8    "       # DIAERESIS
 .
 .
 .
```

You might see that `¡` (0x00A1) is translated into `!`, `¢` (0x00A2) is translated into `c`, `£` (0x00A3) is translated into `lb` and so on...